Water Leaking Into HVAC Duct
So I’m not sure if this is the best place to share this but I want to at least talk to someone about this and get their opinions.
I purchased a condo about 2 years ago in Northwest Indiana. It’s a lower unit, built in the late 70s/early 80s I’d say. Everything passed inspections so nothing really stuck out as being major “pain points” anytime soon.
We closed in October of ‘22 and we didn’t have any issues through the winter which was a relief, however come May of ‘23 we got hit with a huge rain storm. During this storm I heard “leaking water” in my kitchen and eventually traced it rain water from outside leaking into the HVAC ducts located beneath the house.
I contacted our HOA about this and they installed a new downspout outside to help mitigate this. From that time until yesterday that seemed to have helped and fixed the water coming in. I was once again relieved the issue was fixed before it became something bigger.
Flash forward to today, August 27th and we get hit with another large storm. This time the leaking water has returned and is starting to bring water back into our HVAC ducts.
I’m asking to see what more I can do in a situation like this? I’ve already emailed our HOA to see what they can do about this, but at this time they are "exploring options".
Edit 08/29 - I've uploaded a video to Youtube showing the water leaking in. It can be viewed here: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/qxjhD5G3w4s

how high is the water under the home ? you have to fix that

I would install a sump pump to keep the water form flooding the HVAC ducts

some pics and more info about the type of construction, roof, drainage situation is needed. Pics of the exterior of the unit and info as to what the condo association did or plans to do is needed here as well.

This really seems to be an issue concerning the HOA's responsibility. Rather than get DIY advice, you might seek legal advice before trying your own repairs. It might, or might not, be viewed as taking the matter from the HOA if you start to fix it yourself

Is there any kind of crawl space or basement, or does the floor sit directly on soil?

The water only gets to be about an inch or two inside of the HVAC vents.
There is no basement or crawl space that I can directly access. I’m on the bottom of a 4 unit condominium. I can see the water through my floor mounted HVAC vents.
I have contacted the HOA, but they are pushing this down the road until next week. Should this be something I escalate or is it okay to sit for a little while?
